# How to reset time part of timestamp to 00:00:00 in Hive?

Tags: date, hive, timestamp, hiveql, where-clause

I am new to hive.

I have column in one of my seed tables, say seed_timestamp.

example: 
seed.timestamp = '28/04/2020 12:30:54', from this time stamp I want to create a new timestamp such that new_timestamp = '28/04/2020 00:00:00'.

I want to use these timestamps in my where clause of the query such that I check the data from midnight to the seed_timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

In Hive, you can use `to_date()` to truncate the time part of a timestamp, so just:

```
to_date(seed_timestamp)
```

From [the documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions):

> `to_date(string timestamp)`: returns the date part of a timestamp string

Comment: Yes, but that would still result in '28/04/2020' and not the desired '28/04/2020 00:00:00'

Comment: @Smug: it returns a valid date string (or object, depending on your Hive version), that you can use for comparison against a timestamp - which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Sorry If I wasn't clear. I am actually looking to check if a timestamp field lies between two other timestamps. As I mentioned in the question, I have '28/04/2020 12:30:54' but I want to derive '28/04/2020 00:00:00' out of this not '28/04/2020'

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate date with `' 00:00:00.0'`:

```
concat(to_date(seed_timestamp),' 00:00:00.0')
```

It will produce string compatible with timestamp and you can compare. You can also cast it as timestamp:

```
cast(concat(to_date(seed_timestamp),' 00:00:00.0') as timestamp)
```

but it should work without it.